# python 2.7 for loop repeat iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7

first, I'd like to say I'm sorry because my english is not good enough but hopefully you'll understand me.
I searched internet and couldn't find how to do this in python 2.7, I know it could be done with while loop but I'd like to know if it is possible to be done with for, also.

if we have a for loop that looks like this

```
for counter in range(0,len(list)):
    if (condition):
        var=something from dictionary
```

and i need to repeat the same iteration of loop if this condition is true. Tried with `i=i-1` but that didn't work and I later found out that python creates a list of numbers on the beginning of a loop, tried `xrange` also but didn't work. So, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Put a `while condition` inside the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is a `while` loop. It will be much easier for you to control the iterations inside the loop. You can structure it like this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(list):
    if condition:
        var = something from dictionary
    else:
        i++
```

Comment: Did it like this actually, but in c could use for and repeating iteretions so wanted to know if this could be done in python too

Comment: Read this from the python docs on the difference between the `for` loop in python and its C counterpart. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
for l in list:
    if(condition):
        var=getValue()
```

for more examples details you will probably find a good examples at [Python ForLoop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

Comment: need this for pushdown automata so this doesn't work